# elpy-goto-definition and virtualenv

Tags: python, emacs, virtualenv, elpy

I am having some strange problem regarding `elpy-goto-definition` (and some other features) and the use of virtualenvs.

Basically I have two different virtualenvs, in one of them `elpy-goto-definition` works as expected. If I change to the other environment using `pyvenv-workon` **without leaving the buffer**, then I got "No definition found". The problem is, both virtual envs seem to have all the required packages correctly installed.

Here is the elpy-config of the working environment:

```
Emacs.............: 26.1
Elpy..............: 1.34.0
Virtualenv........: AVF-ENV (/home/paulo/environments/AVF-ENV)
Interactive Python: ipython3 7.14.0 (/home/paulo/environments/AVF-ENV/bin/ipython3)
RPC virtualenv....: AVF-ENV (/home/paulo/environments/AVF-ENV)
 Python...........: python3 3.7.3 (/home/paulo/environments/AVF-ENV/bin/python3)
 Jedi.............: 0.18.0
 Rope.............: 0.17.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.4
 Yapf.............: 0.30.0
 Black............: 20.8b1
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/paulo/environments/AVF-ENV/bin/flake8)
```

And here is the config of the environment that is not working:

```
Emacs.............: 26.1
Elpy..............: 1.34.0
Virtualenv........: O2Sat (/home/paulo/environments/O2Sat)
Interactive Python: ipython3 7.19.0 (/home/paulo/environments/O2Sat/bin/ipython3)
RPC virtualenv....: O2Sat (/home/paulo/environments/O2Sat)
 Python...........: python3 3.7.3 (/home/paulo/environments/O2Sat/bin/python3)
 Jedi.............: 0.18.0
 Rope.............: 0.18.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.4
 Yapf.............: 0.30.0
 Black............: 20.8b1
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/paulo/environments/O2Sat/bin/flake8)
```

The only relevant difference I can see is the different version for Rope, which I fixed without any improvement.

`elpy-doc` is also not working in one of the envs, but is on the other.

I would appreciate any suggestion of what may be causing this behavior.
Thank you,